# Using variables in git alias

Tags: git, git-alias, posh-git

I'm trying to create an alias for checking out the master branch and merging the branch I was on before switching. Right now, my alias looks like this:
`med = "!f() { git checkout master; git merge ${1}; git branch -d ${1};  }; f"`

It means that every time I want to use it, I have to call it using the current branch's name: `git med topic`. What I want is avoid it, calling `git med` without arguments.

I know that I can get the current branch's name like this: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`, but after I have switched to master, I can no longer use it. So, I need to save it in a variable before switching to master.

How do I work with variables in git alias?

I'm on Windows, using posh-git.

Comment: Have you tried `med = "!f() {BRANCH=\`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD\`; git checkout master; git merge $BRANCH; git branch -d $BRANCH; }; f"`

Comment: For some reason `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` is commonly quoted as the way to get the current branch name, but this is subtly wrong: it produces the literal string `HEAD`, which is *not* a branch name, when you are not on a branch at all.  For a case like this, use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` and check exit status (it will fail with a `fatal: ...` message when HEAD is detached).  In any case @Creynders is right: just invoke the shell.  (You could use `git check-ref-format --branch @{-1}` but it does not handle detached HEAD cases correctly either.)

Comment: @Creynders thanks! It worked for me. I'm just not experienced at all in shell scripts. 

Please make this a separate entry so that I could mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a combination of my comment and @torek 's:

```
med = "!f() {BRANCH=`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`; git checkout master; git merge $BRANCH; git branch -d $BRANCH; }; f"
```

which seems to work. (And bails out early, rather than late, if you're in a detached HEAD state)

Comment: I had to put a space between `{` and `BRANCH=` for this to work for me (i.e. `!f() { BRANCH=...`). I'm using windows and running the command through the terminal in jetbrains rider IDE.

Comment: ```med = "!BRANCH=`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`; git checkout develop; git pull; git merge $BRANCH; git checkout $BRANCH "```  worked just fine for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157669/using-variables-in-git-alias/74978712#answer-74978712

Answer (score 0):

I found in bash (debian) that wrapping the alias in double quotes didn't work.

I had to use single quotes:

```
'!f() { BRANCH=`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`; git checkout master; git merge $BRANCH; git branch -d $BRANCH; }; f'`
```